# Is IN Query used index in MySql or not?

Tags: mysql, indexed

I have a query like

```
SELECT * FROM Table_name WHERE column1 = '1' AND  column2 IN ('1','2','3');
```

And  index exists on `(column1, column2, column3)`. Is my above query used index I have created or not? Basically I am confused with the `IN` keyword, without this it is using, but with `IN` I am not sure. Please explain me.

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: Try writing `EXPLAIN` before your query and see the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is *capable* of using indices with `IN` .. now, *is* MySQL using indices in the *particular* query? Well, *ask the query planner*!

In this case an index over `(column1, column2, ..)` *could* be used - because all the leftward components have been satisfied. That is, an index seek could be done on column1 (for `=`), and then column2 (for `IN`). But again, *ask the query planner* as unexpected plans are not unheard of; just because the query planner *could* choose an index doesn't mean that it will.

See [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html), for how to ask:

> When EXPLAIN is used with an explainable statement, MySQL displays information from the optimizer about the statement execution plan. That is, MySQL explains how it would process the statement, including information [like index usage] about how tables are joined and in which order ..
>
> .. With the help of EXPLAIN, you can see where you should add indexes to tables so that the statement executes faster by using indexes to find rows.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can use indexes with `IN` conditions. If you only have an index on `column2`, it will most likely be used. If you have indexes on each of `column1` and `column2`, only one of them can be used, and the query planner will have to decide which one seems better for a particular query. If you have a composite index on `(column1, column2)` then it should be able to use that index to match both columns in the `WHERE` clause.